Google Ads to Google BigQuery Data Transfer failed
Dear Google Community Support Team,
I hope this message finds you well.
We have encountered an issue related to our billing account. It was inactive during the period from October 7, 2024, to November 5, 2024. As a result of this inactivity, the automatic Data Transfer from Google Ads to Google BigQuery did not log any data into our tables, such as ads_ShoppingProductStats, among others.
We kindly request your guidance on how to address this issue. Specifically, we are looking for a solution or recommendation to retrieve (or backfill) the missing data for the aforementioned period so that our BigQuery datasets are complete.
Your assistance in resolving this matter will be greatly appreciated. Please let us know if you require any additional details or if there are specific steps we need to follow.
Thank you in advance for your support.
Best regards,
Slavi
Developer at HD
